# More efficient way of converting json to panda dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, nested

I have a simple json file and i have to convert it into a panda datarame and then to csv. Some sample records from the file are:

```
    {
      '11': ['A', 'fried', 'is', 'a', 'nice', 'companion', '.'],  
      '2':  ['Let', 'the', 'things', 'happen', '.'], 
      '33': ['There', 'is', 'always', 'a', 'way', 'out', '.'],
      '4':  ['The', 'birds', 'are', 'flying', '.'],
       ... more than 500,000 records
    }
```

Resulting dataframe:

```
    11,    A friend is a nice companion.
     2,    Let the things happen.            
    33,    There is always a way out.
     4,    The birds are flying.    
    ..... upto 500,000 records
```

The code to convert it is given below and its working perfectly fine:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.read_json('my_file.json', orient = 'index')

df = df[df.columns[1:]].apply(lambda x:' '.join(x.dropna().astype(str)),axis=1)

#df = df.apply(lambda x: x.replace(',',' '))
print(df)

df.to_csv('outPutFile1.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

I want to know that is there a more efficient solution? As i have to merge all the columns into one column because of ',' considered as a separator by pandas. May be converting the json directly to pandas dataframe without merging all the columns into one ?

I will appreciate some help.
Thanks

Comment: why do you first `','.join()` and then remove the comma. why not just `' '.join()`?

Comment: use `' '.join()` and remove the second `apply`

Comment: got it but what about not using .join at all and using something else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fastest way to convert your json file to csv file format you want is as below

```
# load json file to a dictionary
with open('my_file.json') as f:
    my_file_dictionary = json.load(f)    

# save dictionary keys and value(text separated by space) to a csv
with open('outPutFile1.csv', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
    [fp.write('{0},{1}\n'.format(key, ' '.join(value))) for key, value in my_file_dictionary.items()]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am getting a csv file with your code but the longer text is divided into many columns and not just one column as it was with my code. I think as there are many single quotes, double quotes, commas etc. in the text so that might be reason or perhaps more than one space is causing this.

Comment: @codeDB, you can seperate your csv file by a tab (`\t`), ie `fp.write('{0}\t{1}\n'.form.....`

Comment: i did that and it did not change any thing but combined first and second columns together so keys in first column are merged to text.